# Uncertainty about the term "image lable file" (ITK)

Tags: itk

I've been using ITK recently and I'm not really skillful on it, so I
apologize if my question seems childish !
here is the question: I've built a couple of ITK Examples on my machine (Win
7 x64) successfully and then tried to run an example to test the result, as
I was interested to watershed segmentation I tried it (WS3D), but except the
input and output image files which has to be defined, then it needs an
additional parameter to be defined called : LabelImageFile, exactly like
this :

WS3D InputImageFile LabelImageFile OutputImageFile

And unfortunately I have no idea what is LabelImageFile, how can I obtain a
Label Image for a specific image ?I'd be so much grateful if anyone can help
me, many thanks in advance,
Shawn

Comment: No answer after two days ?
No one is expert here in image processing ?

Answer (score 2):

The watershed segmentation algorithm looks for a function f that is a continuous height function defined over an image domain. Such that a catchment basin is defined as the set of points whose paths of steepest descent terminate at the same local minimum of f. This catchment basin is your watershed result.
The label image that the filter is expecting is the function f or the height function. You can generate one such image by applying gradient magnitude to the original image.